# Where can I find Stacraft 2 installation story ingame?

Tags: starcraft-2

I want to view again the SC2 installation story, but I cannot find it. Any clue if it is playable trough the SC2 GUI interface?

Specifically this video

Comment: What do you mean by "installation" story? Like the Campaign story?

Comment: @Sorean - there was a slideshow that came with the game's original installer, mostly recapping the series while it copied files.  It probably only came with a physical game disc, I dont think the BNet installer does this.

Answer (score 2):

The closest thing i found was under Campaingn -> Wings of Liberty -> more -> Story so far.

this is not exactly what you are looking for but i can´t find the slideshow on my hd.

[image: Storyvideo]